# "TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress" even when transaction interceptor is applied - hibernate-5 and spring-4.3

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-transactions, transactional

I'm facing this TransactionRequiredException even when transaction interceptor appeared to be applied:

```
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.checkTransactionNeeded(SessionImpl.java:3393)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1386)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SessionFactoryUtils.flush(SessionFactoryUtils.java:144)
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionSynchronization.beforeCommit(SpringSessionSynchronization.java:95)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationUtils.triggerBeforeCommit(TransactionSynchronizationUtils.java:95)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.triggerBeforeCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:932)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:744)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:487)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
at my.pkg.entity.impl.StoreImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$73283c3f.merge(<generated>)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.setClient(LoginController.java:243)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.setupUserSession(LoginController.java:185)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:121)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d71b2e05.invoke(<generated>)
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:651)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$442b15b7.login(<generated>)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:114)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
............
```

Here is what i'm using:

```
Hibernate-5.2 (hibernate-entitymanager-5.1, hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1)
Spring-4.3.3 - (tried 4.3.2 as well, same error)
```

My dispatcher <servlet>-servlet.xml is empty, and all spring config is in applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="my.pkg.controller, my.pkg.entity"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven enable-matrix-variables="true" content-negotiation-manager="contentNegotiationManager" />
<import resource="db-config.xml" />
```

db-config.xml has:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>.......hbm.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.autocommit">false</prop> 
            <prop key="current_session_context_class">thread</prop >
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    .......
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:advice id="transactionalAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes> 
        <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="find*" read-only="true"/>
        <tx:method name="*" />  
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <!-- applying this aop on other job classes -->
</aop:config>

<tx:advice id="traxSupportedAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
    <tx:attributes>
        <tx:method name="*" propagation="SUPPORTS" />
    </tx:attributes>
</tx:advice>
<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* my.pkg.entity.*Home.*(..))" advice-ref="traxSupportedAdvice" />
</aop:config>
```

My my.pkg.entity.impl.*Impl classes extends from my.pkg.entity.*Home classes (i'm using jboss tools to auto-generate <entity> and <entity>Home classes), and all *Impl classes (not *Home classes) are annotated with @Transactional as well. *Home are indicated in aop with propagation "Supports" advice. 
LoginController.setClient() is annotated with @Transactional.

I can't figure out what am i doing wrong or missing.
I did try to search on SOF and on google, but could not find what could be applied here.

Let me know if any other info is required. Please also let me know if i'm deviating from any std/preferred configuration approach here.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The @Transactional annotation for LoginController.setClient is not applied. Because it is a bean internal call.
You see this in the Stacktrace

```
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.setClient(LoginController.java:243)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.setupUserSession(LoginController.java:185)
at my.pkg.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:121)
```

You can maybe start it with the login method. But I don't have enough details to tell.